# Activity Indicator for UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uicollectionview, activity-indicator

I have a UICollectionView that reads data from Firebase, and I want some kind of activity indicator while it's reading data.

I want the activity indicator to start running as soon as the UICollectionView tab in the TabBar is hit, and I want it to stop and the view/uicollectionView to load once loading from Firebase is done.

I saw this post:

[Show Activity Indicator while data load in collectionView Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46650183/show-activity-indicator-while-data-load-in-collectionview-swift)

But I could not understand it fully because I did not know how to integrate my UICollectionView there.

EDIT:

This is my code that reads from Firebase:

```
self.ref = Database.database().reference()
            let loggedOnUserID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid


            if let currentUserID = loggedOnUserID
            {
                // Retrieve the products and listen for changes
                self.databaseHandle = self.ref?.child("Users").child(currentUserID).child("Products").observe(.childAdded, with:
                    { (snapshot) in

                        // Code to execute when new product is added
                        let prodValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                        let prodName = prodValue?["Name"] as? String ?? ""
                        let prodPrice = prodValue?["Price"] as? Double ?? -1
                        let prodDesc = prodValue?["Description"] as? String ?? ""
                        let prodURLS = prodValue?["MainImage"] as? String
                        let prodAmount = prodValue?["Amount"] as? Int ?? 0
                        let prodID = snapshot.key

                        let prodToAddToView = Product(name: prodName, price: prodPrice, currency: "NIS", description: prodDesc, location: "IL",
                                                      toSell: false, toBuy: false, owner: currentUserID, uniqueID: prodID, amount: prodAmount, mainImageURL: prodURLS)


                        self.products.append(prodToAddToView)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async
                            {
                                self.MyProductsCollection.reloadData()
                        }
                }
                ) // Closes observe function
```

Comment: You don't have to explicitly understand how to integrate activityIndicator with collectionView. You have to understand how do a  UI update while doing a background task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let activityView = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .whiteLarge)

// waiy until main view shows 
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

   super.viewDidAppear(animated)

   // create a hover view that covers all screen with opacity 0.4 to show a waiting action
    let fadeView:UIView = UIView()
    fadeView.frame = self.view.frame
    fadeView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    fadeView.alpha = 0.4

   // add fade view to main view
    self.view.addSubview(fadeView)
 // add activity to main view
    self.view.addSubview(activityView)
    activityView.hidesWhenStopped = true
    activityView.center = self.view.center
// start animating activity view
    activityView.startAnimating()

  self.ref = Database.database().reference()
            let loggedOnUserID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid


            if let currentUserID = loggedOnUserID
            {
                // Retrieve the products and listen for changes
                self.databaseHandle = self.ref?.child("Users").child(currentUserID).child("Products").observeSingleEvent(.value, with:
                    { (snapshot) in

                        // Code to execute when new product is added
                        let prodValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                        let prodName = prodValue?["Name"] as? String ?? ""
                        let prodPrice = prodValue?["Price"] as? Double ?? -1
                        let prodDesc = prodValue?["Description"] as? String ?? ""
                        let prodURLS = prodValue?["MainImage"] as? String
                        let prodAmount = prodValue?["Amount"] as? Int ?? 0
                        let prodID = snapshot.key

                        let prodToAddToView = Product(name: prodName, price: prodPrice, currency: "NIS", description: prodDesc, location: "IL",
                                                      toSell: false, toBuy: false, owner: currentUserID, uniqueID: prodID, amount: prodAmount, mainImageURL: prodURLS)


                        self.products.append(prodToAddToView)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async
                            {
                                self.MyProductsCollection.reloadData()
                                  // remove the hover view as now we have data
                               fadeView.removeFromSuperview()
                               // stop animating the activity 
                               self.activityView.stopAnimating()
                        }
                }
                ) // Closes observe function
```

Comment: I'm not sure what to replace "fetchPosts()" with.

Comment: I added the code, and it seems to be working like before, no activity indication...

Comment: @Sh_Khan : DispatchQueue.main.async is outside DispatchQueue.global. Perhaps that is why, activityIndicator is not displaying.

Comment: @Nitish Actually i copied the code from the link to illustrate it to him

Comment: I Edited my post  and added a snippet of code I wrote that I'm using to read from Firebase.

Comment: Ok, that worked, but... It showed the indicator, then 1 product only (out of 5) loaded, then the indicator was gone, then the other 4 products loaded. How can I make sure ALL products load before indicator is gone ?

Comment: your observe is childAdded so for every child added callback will be called

Comment: I see. How can I fix that ?

Comment: wait , i will edit it now

Comment: This does not compile:

Cannot assign value of type 'Void?' to type 'DatabaseHandle?' (aka 'Optional<UInt>')

Comment: editttttttt,..........

Comment: Can you open chat please ?

Comment: see remove left hand equation "self.databaseHandle = " no need for it as it's a single observe

Comment: After changing to "observeSIngleEvent", it only loads ONE product (Instead of 5) and even reads data wrong

Comment: Products added dynamically ??? can u show me database structure

Comment: Yes, products can be added using an "Add product button". What do you mean database structure ?

Comment: you need to read about **.observe**  , **observeSingleEvent**  also there is a difference between **.value** and **.childAdded**

Answer (score 0):

I mean `UIActivityIndicatorView` isn't hard to work with, you display it when fetching data, and stop it when done.

```
private lazy var indicator : UIActivityIndicatorView = { // here we simply declaring the indicator along some properties 
    let _indicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
    // change the color
    _indicator.color = .black
    // when you call stopAnimation on this indicator, it will hide automatically
    _indicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    return _indicator
}()
```

**Now where you want to place it?**  you can either placed it into your parent's view, or into your navigationBar. (I choose to place into the right side of the navigationBar )

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: indicator)
```

**Now say you have this function that return data (via callbacks) from some apis.**

```
// this callback emits data from a background queue
    func fetchPost(completion:@escaping(Array<Any>?, Error?) -> ()) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
           // ... do work 
             completion([], nil) // call your completionHandler based either error or data
        }
    }


/* now let's called that fetchPost function and load data into your 
  collectionView, but before let's started this indicator */


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: indicator)
    indicator.startAnimating()

    fetchPost { [weak self] (data, err) in
        // go to the main queue to update our collectionView
        // and stop the indicator
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            // stop animation
            self?.indicator.startAnimating()
            // do something we have an error
            if let _err = err {}

            if let _data = data {
                // fill array for collectionView
                // reload the collectionView
                self?.collectionView?.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not be starting the activity view in your lazy property.

Comment: yeah my mistake @rmaddy, since it would defeat the lazy initializer purpose.

Comment: Can you please show me the fixed code ? Btw, Look at my edit :) I added the snippet of code I wrote to read from Firebase

Comment: what fixed code @Ofri

Comment: @Lamar you said you made a mistake..

Comment: yea i fixed it already